# Extract data without Json format - Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm performing the following extract query in CSV and it works perfectly:

```
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://my_bucket/test*.csv',
    format = 'CSV',
    overwrite = TRUE,
    header = TRUE
    field_delimiter = ','
    ) AS (
  SELECT
      column1,
      column2,
      column3
  FROM
      My_table
);
```

I would like the same query but in Json format

```
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://my_bucket/test*.json',
    format = 'json',
    overwrite = TRUE,
    header = TRUE
    field_delimiter = ','
    ) AS (
  SELECT
      column1,
      column2,
      column3
  FROM
      My_table
);
```

However it doesn't work the way I'm writing, I've looked in the bigquery documentation and haven't found the solution

Comment: `json` format is definitely supported. attributes like `field_delimiter `, `header`, etc. are not relevant/compatible with `json` format - that might be a source of issue you have

Comment: What's the format of your JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json format is definitely supported.

attributes like `field_delimiter` , `header`, etc. are not relevant/compatible with json format - that is a source of issue you have

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this way it worked below:

```
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://my_bucket/file_*.json',
    format = 'JSON',
    overwrite = TRUE
    ) AS (
  SELECT FROM)
```